# How to remove old identities from Mail?

Tags: mail.app

I previously had four e-mail accounts (and thus four identities) set up in the Mail app. I have now removed two of these accounts but when I compose a new e-mail the "From" drop-down box still lists four identities.

How do I remove the identities from the removed accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently removing the file
~/Saved Application State/com.apple.mail.savedState
resolved Daniel's problem without resorting to a factory reset.
Mac OS X is great for saving your progress but once in a while that savedState file causes these types of problems.
Happy Day!

Answer (score 0):

That is interesting because I currently have 8 email accounts with only 4 of them "enabled" in the Mail preferences.

When I go to the new mail>from drop-down box I only see the four accounts that I have enabled.

So, you may have a damaged preferences file.

1) Double check that you have deleted the old accounts in the Preferences>Accounts.

2) Make sure you have deleted the old accounts' outgoing mail servers from your servers list in Preferences>Accounts>Outgoing Mail Server>Edit SMTP Server List

3) Try using disk utility to repair the drive and repair permissions on the off chance that a file is damaged and can be repaired. Shut down all other applications first.

4) If these fail then you could delete the preferences plist file from your preferences folder. But this may require you to re-enter some of your information in Mail. (Try just moving the plist to the trash first though with Mail not running, then re-open Mail. That way you can move it back if it does not have the desired result.)

Comment: Nope, none of this works sorry.

Comment: Double check the preferences>accounts>email address field to be sure you only have one address in that field. Delete the Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist and the Saved Application State/com.apple.mail.savedState from your Library folder if you haven't already.

Comment: If this fails and it still bugs you, you could try to select just the mailboxes for the accounts you deleted or delete all the Mail support files and reset to factory defaults. This would require setting your email accounts back up. Warning! This would remove your mail messages from your computer. Make sure they are backed up or on the server to be downloaded again. See this thread for which files to delete: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5118986

Comment: Looks like deleting `~/Saved Application State/com.apple.mail.savedState/*` did the trick, thanks! Care to put that as the answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I added another answer in case one of those other things can help someone else. Glad you got it straightened out.